# Using Autocomplete populate more than one field

Tags: jquery, list, autocomplete

I am trying to implement auto complete via jquery auto complete plugin. 
I have used the script from here [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). 
I currently have a field called 'Search Infections' where I am storing the '**Description**'.

```
<tr>
<td>Search Infection</td>
<td>
<input id="tags" type="text"  size="80" /></td>
</tr>
```

this works fine for autocomplete.

I also have a field called 'Short code' in which I want to store the **Code**.

```
<tr>
<td>Short Code</td>
<td>
<input id="" type="text"  size="15" /></td>
</tr>
```

Is there a way I could store the code in the 'short code' field when a user search the Description in the infection field?

Please, please help.

```
  CODE and DESCRIPTION list.

  ---------------------------------------------------------
  Code  Description
  ---------------------------------------------------------
  ID01  Actinomycosis
  ID02  Aspergillosis
  ID03  Bacteraemia / blood stream infection/ Septicaemia
  ID04  Bacterial meningitis
  ID05  Bronchiectasis
  ID06  Candidiasis
  ID07  Carotid patch infection
  ID08  Cellulitis
  ID09  Cerebral abscess
  ID10  Cholangitis
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  =====================================================================

  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
                  "Actinomycosis",
                  "Aspergillosis",
                  "Bacteraemia / blood stream infection/ Septicaemia",
                  "Bacterial meningitis",
                  "Bronchiectasis",
                  "Candidiasis",
                  "Carotid patch infection",
                  "Cellulitis",
                  "Cerebral abscess",
                  "Cholangitis" 
                    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is not clear for me, you are trying to get the Id of the infection in the 'short code' td when doing an autocomplete (but in behind)?

Comment: I haven't tested, but I think you should be able to bind an onchange to the completion field to accomplish what you want.  $('#tags').bind('change', function(e) { //do your thing });

Comment: One more question, are you using PHP for this?

Comment: i am using csp (cache server page). i basically want to link the code with the description whilst doing the autocomplete. (yes the code populates in the behind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to this link.

That's sample code is :

```
var availableTags = [
    {key:"ID01",value:"Actinomycosis"},
    {key:"ID02",value:"Aspergillosis"},
    {key:"ID03",value:"Bacteraemia / blood stream infection/ Septicaemia"}
];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5EsAb/3/

Answer (score 0):

I made this for you:

I also used a plugin for text events:

http://www.zurb.com/playground/javascripts/plugins/jquery.textchange.min.js

(to clean the short code when infection doesn't match with less code)

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/SUckd/1/

Comment: this is exactally what i wanted. thanks. when i load it on my page it doesent seem to work i am using <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Oscar many thanks ... works great. everyones help much appreciated.

Comment: @jk1844 No problem, I am here to help. Don't forget to check this answer as the correct one :-)

Comment: one last question, actually i have about more than 100 infections. is it possible to have a scroll bar if more that 10 results?

Comment: this jquery autocomplete plugin will match things for not losing it's design, for example if I write 'C' will filter everything with 'C' and design will look good, so no problem for the scroll bar :-) One question, are you getting the infections from a database?

Comment: i do have a table in the database with all the infections. is there a way to look up(or search) the data from the table, rather than list them in jquery script? thanks

Comment: Are you using PHP? yes, there is a way to get the elements from db using jquery, its easy but I need to know the language

Comment: i use intersystems Cache, csp (cache server page). [link](http://www.intersystems.com/cache/index.html) similar to SQL

Comment: Uhm, thats new for me, but what programming language are you using for your system?

Comment: The language itself is called 'cache' we create forms on the csp pages (works like html page or like ASP). we query the database using cachesql similar to sql.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry thats new for me, I heard about it but never use it, I know how to get data from db using PHP and jQuery, not CSP :-)

Comment: probably you could give me the idea of how to introgate data from db using jquery and/or PHP. iwill see if i could adopt it in Cache. many thanks.